# Existence of a measure on semi-algebra

Tags: probability, measure-theory, outer-measure

Suppose a semi-algebra (/algebra/sigma algebra) $\mathbb{S}$ is given. I know the definition of measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{S}$. But how can I show the existence of such measure? If we have a measure on Semi-algebra then we can extend it to sigma algebra. But to extend the measure I have to have a measure on the Semi-algebra at the first place. Right?

Comment: "I can clearly define a measure $\mu$ on $S$"—if you have already defined a measure on your semi-algebra, why are you concerned about its existence? If you meant to say you know the definition of a measure on a semi-algebra and you wish to exhibit one always exists for any semi-algebra that's a different story...

Comment: Yes, that is is what I mean. Sorry for that. Now I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Defining the measure on the semi-algebra will be done differently for different examples.  For example, in the real line, your semi-algebra is all intervals of the form $[a,b)$ and the measure of $[a,b)$ is $b-a$.